# Finding $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\frac{\ln(n)}n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}k$

Tags: real-analysis

For a given sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,…,a_n$, if $\lim\limits_{n→∞}=a$, find$$\lim_{n→∞}\frac{\ln(n)}n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}k.$$
Can there be no question which a person is not even able to start? If I have no idea how to start a question how can I say what I did?

Comment: It would be helpful if you worded your question a little more clearly. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with what we know. We are given that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$, but you will see that we don't actually need to use this. All that matters is that the sequence is bounded (convergence implies bounded). i.e.

$$\exists \; M \in \Bbb R \; | \; |a_k|<M \; \; \forall \; k \in \Bbb N$$

Also, the Euler constant should come in handy, and it is defined as $$\gamma := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k - \ln(n)\bigg)$$

and implies that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k - \ln(n)-\gamma\bigg|=0$$

Using L'Hopital's rule, we see that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\big[\ln(n)\big]^2}{n}=0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0 $$

Thus, we have:

\begin{align}
& \bigg|\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {a_k}{k} \bigg|\\
\leq & \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {|a_k|}{k}\bigg| \\
\leq & \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {M}{k}\bigg| \\
= & M\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\bigg(\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k}-\ln(n)-\gamma \bigg|+\bigg|\ln(n)+\gamma\bigg|\bigg) \\
= & M\bigg(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\bigg)\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k}-\ln(n)-\gamma \bigg|+M\frac{\big[\ln(n)\big]^2}{n}+M\gamma \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\\
\rightarrow & M(0)|0| + M(0) + M\gamma (0) \\
= & 0
\end{align}

which implies that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {a_k}{k}=0$$

Comment: will there be a different method which does not involve so advance concepts

Comment: which of the above concepts do you consider advanced?

Answer (score 1):

First consider the case where $a_k = a$ for all $k$. Then the sum becomes a sum of $1/k$, which can be approximated by comparing it to the integral of $1/x$ in some way that I forget but involves the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Anyway I think you get something that converges to $0$, and then you can argue that if $a_k \to a$ then it isn't different enough from the above case, so will also converge to $0$.

Comment: could not understand the last few lines.